# BibLaTeX: Origlanguage chinese

Tags: biblatex

I would like to cite this book:

```
@book{hua1982,
    author = {{H}ua, {L}oo-{K}eng},
    title = {{I}ntroduction to {N}umber {T}heory},
    publisher = {{S}pringer-{V}erlag},
    address = {{B}erlin and {H}eidelberg and {N}ew {Y}ork},
    year = {1982},
    origlanguage = {chinese},
    translator = {{S}hiu, {P}eter}
}
```

Unfortunately, BibLaTeX does not know the key `chinese` (at least when using it in German). How can I add this language?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Indeed `bibaltex` does not know Chinese and the bibstring `langchinese`. You have to teach it.

Answer (score 1):

```
\NewBibliographyString{langchinese}
\NewBibliographyString{fromchinese}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  langchinese = {Chinesisch},
  fromchinese = {aus dem Chinesischen},
}
```

Comment: @L47 Great! If this answer helped you, please consider up-voting it (you can't at the moment, due to reputation constraints) and accepting it using the green checkmark on the left, to show that it helped you. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers